# Error 21 Device not ready while deletion registery keys?

Tags: winapi, registry

.
I am new to c++ registery operations.I have got an assignment to do operations on registery.

I have created a menudriven program for 1.creating key, 2.creating value,3.deleting key,4. deleting value.

all operations works fine except deleting key for the more than one times.

following is my code for deleting operation in my program.

```
case 3:


                cout<<"Following keys can be deleted:";
                /****/
                        HKEY hTestKey;
                        if( RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_CURRENT_USER,TEXT("SOFTWARE\\MasterSachin"), 0,KEY_READ,
                            &hTestKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS
                          )
                          {
                              QueryKey(hTestKey);
                          }
                           RegCloseKey(hTestKey);
                /*****/
                   cout<<"Enter the key name to be deleted:";
                   cin>>delKeyName;

                status=RegDeleteKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER ,strcat(keyPath,delKeyName));



                if(ERROR_SUCCESS==status)
                {
                    cout<<"registry Key "<<delKeyName <<" deleted successfully . . ! ! !";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"Error while deleting key...Error code:"<<status;
                }
                break;
```

How it works?
--> When i select case 3 for the first time it shows me all the sub keys of the in a list and asks for the key name to enter for deletion.  When i enter key name ,it deletes that key and show success message..,,,But when i select case 3 again ,then it shows me list of remaining subkeys(previously deleted key is not shown).when i enter anather name of key to delete  it shows me error code 21 i.e The device is not ready.
     I observed that when i run my program for the first time it deletes one key and then it starts showing error in subsequent trials..

I searched a lot for removing this error but it was fruitless.

Can anyone tell me where i am making mistake or i am missing something to do . . .

thanks in advance . . .

I want to delete these keys continuously one after anather by inputting key names.

Comment: I have no experience with the Registry API, but when looking at [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I see: "The subkey to be deleted must not have subkeys." Do the remaining keys have subkeys? If so, this might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @lethal-guitar  . .No, no subkey is having anather subkeys  . .in fact it works for the first time when i run my program ,so that must not be the issue . .

Comment: Well, do you always try it on the same key when deleting the first time?

Comment: no ,,i try defferent key each time ..when i delete the key the key it gets deleted actually . .so it does not show me the same key again which is deleted  . .only remaining keys are shown . .

Comment: Are you sure that the **second** time you do `strcat(keyPath,delKeyName)` you don't end up with an inavlid key name?